# Combine, map() vs tryMap() operators

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I have been playing with Apple's `Combine` framework, There I found couple of operators `map() & tryMap()` or `allSatisfy() & tryAllSatisfy`

many operators in Combine follows this pattern, I wonder what does this meant for.

I gone through with many operator, most of them have prefixed `try`. If some one can let me know in most plain manner, that would really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The `try` variants give the accompanying function the opportunity to throw an error. If the function *does* throw an error, that error is passed downstream (and the entire pipeline is completed, failing in good order).

So, for example, `map` takes a function, but you cannot say `throw` in that function. If you would like to be able to say `throw`, use `tryMap` instead. And so on.

Answer (score 3):

The `map` operator cannot introduce failures. If the upstream `Failure` type is `Never`, then after `map`, the `Failure` type is still `Never`. If the upstream `Failure` type is `DecodingError`, then after `map`, the `Failure` type is still `DecodingError`:

```
let up0: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = ...

let down0: AnyPublisher<String, Never> = up0
//                              ^^^^^ still Never, like up0
    .map { String($0) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let up1: AnyPublisher<Int, DecodingError> = ...

let down1: AnyPublisher<String, DecodingError> = up1
//                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ still DecodingError, like up1
    .map { String($0) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

The `tryMap` operator ends the stream with a failure completion if the closure throws an error. A throwing closure can throw any `Error`. The error type is not restricted. So `tryMap` always changes the `Failure` type to `Error`:

```
let up2: AnyPublisher<Int, Never> = ...

let down2: AnyPublisher<String, Error> = up2
//                              ^^^^^ changed from Never to Error
    .tryMap { String($0) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()

let up3: AnyPublisher<Int, DecodingError> = ...

let down3: AnyPublisher<String, Error> = up3
//                              ^^^^^ changed from DecodingError to Error
    .tryMap { String($0) }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: I definitely agree with this! In my https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/operators/operatorsTransformersBlockers/operatorsmap.html I particularly note the use of tryMap to change the error type downstream.